# Converting a string to double using c_str() in C++

Tags: c++, string, double

Is it not reccomended to convert a string in such way:

```
string input = "81.312";
double val = atof(input.c_str());
```

Comment: It should be right, are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Nick: The problem is that you (probably) want to get errors if the input is not a valid number, but `atof` just returns zero.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DO NOT use `std::atof` in C++. That doesn't check for input error.

Use [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof). That checks for error also and throws exception accordingly.

Also, it takes `std::string const &` as argument. So you don't have to pass `input.c_str()`. Just do this:

```
double value = std::stod(input);
```

Comment: I get an error 'stod' was not declared in this scope, and I have included <string>

Comment: @Josh - `stod` was added with C++11.

Comment: @Josh: depends what compiler you use. You need to get the latest version and put it in C++11 mode using some command line option.

Answer (score 0):

It is not wrong, but more right would be to use boost::lexical_cast.

You should also check if these tools handle NANs and INFs correctly.